# SVN Error: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem

Tags: svn

I installed the ffg and subsequently the SVN document on [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008):

```
1. Subversion-Setup-Subversion-1.5.1.en-us
2. Apache-httpd-2.2.19-win32-x86-no_ssl
3. TSVN- TortoiseSVN-1.6.16.21511-win32-svn-1.6.17
```

Here are the settings for `Location`:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNListParentPath on
  SVNParentPath C:\SVN
</Location>
```

When I tried to open the URL in the browser, http://localhost/svn/test, I got this error:

> SVN Error: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

First, the Apache error log file contains more information about such errors.

Since you're using Windows Server 2008 and the repositories are on the C drive, it's possible that the access restrictions prevent the Apache process from accessing them. Add the user the Apache process runs under (could be `SYSTEM` if it runs as a service) to the `C:\SVN` folder recursively with full access.

And make sure that there actually is a repository at `C:\SVN\test`

Comment: Stefan, can you add some more information? Most importantly, what is the name of the Apache error log file and where is it located? Less important, a description of *how* the access rights are recursively changed, perhaps with a screenshot?

Comment: On Linux, e.g. [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian), e.g. [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi), the error log file is likely `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (and the Apache access log is `/var/log/apache2/access.log`).

Answer (score 3):

#### My situation

I moved my SVN data from one server to another, got everything setup and working great, except that when I created a new file and tried and commit it to the SVN, I got the following error (ONLY on commit of a new file (add), update works fine (existing files)).

```
$ svn commit -am 'testing commit'
Adding         trunk/public_html/mynewtestfile.txt
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
svn: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
```

My Vhosts is set up in a way that I can have multiple repositories within the same directory, and I can access them like so:

```
http://svn.mydomain.com/repo1
http://svn.mydomain.com/repo2
```

It turns out that in my `vhosts.conf` (or `httpd.conf` or wherever you setup your virtual hosts) is using `SVNParentPath` so that I can access my SVN repositories using the URLs above.

**Q.** How do I setup multiple SVN repositories in the same directory on my server?

**A**: https://serverfault.com/questions/461144/vhost-setup-for-multiple-svn-repositories

Now, I could have either setup the SVN in my vhosts separately to fix this error (check my answer on the ServerFault post) (`svn: Could not open...`), or I just had to create another SVN repo in my repos directory called `error`.

I created this repository like so:

```
#Inside your repository's directory, create an error repository.
svnadmin create error
```

This seemed to resolve all my errors with committing code through my SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! The problem is file access permissions. For me, the simplest solution was to move the repository to the folder where Apache has read/write permissions.

In my case (I am using CollabNet Subversion Edge):

```
C:\csvn\data\repositories
```