# Can not access a new repository with svn

Tags: apache, svn, windows-7

I have been looking for a solution to my SVN problem but have not yet found one. We have been using svn for a number of years without problems but I have been unsuccessful adding a new project as of late.

SVN is installed on a central computer we use as a server running Windows 7. We have TortoiseSVN installed on our clients and on the server. To create new projects in the past we would log onto the server and execute `svnadmin create [drive]:/archive/new project`. We would then create the trunk, tags, and branches folders using the repo-browser. Once that was done we could use TortoiseSVN to import the code on our local machines to create the archive.

Now when I create a new project archive the client computers return the error: "Could not open the requested SVN filesystem". The repo-browser says the same thing. I can perform all of the usual SVN activities from the client computers on all of the existing repositories, just not on any new ones. Also, if I use the repo-browser on the server it works.

What I have done so far is uninstall subversion and TortoiseSVN from the server and reinstalled TortoiseSVN 1.9.4 along with the command line tools and recreated the svn service. I also updated TortoiseSVN to 1.9.4 so there shouldn't be any version conflicts but it still does not work. Since everything works as long as I am on the server I suspect the problem lies in the network access configuration but I don't know what would be different from when it was working.

Also note that when I try to browse the archive with Firefox I can navigate down into the project trees of the older projects but not any new ones. Firefox displays:

```
<D:error>
    <C:error/><m:human-readable errcode="160043">Could not open the requested SVN filesystem</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

PS: Access to the repositories on the server is through Apache 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>1. Using file-type access to repository over LAN is always **The Bad Idea (tm)**
2. Source of your problem (except the above) is changing format of repository-storage between version and inability of old versions read directly repositories of new versions: your client's SVN is **older**, than server-side (and worse - use|know only old format of repo)</strike>

Check version on client's hosts (I suppose, they are pre-1.6) and

- update to version, compatible with server's version (1.7+ for 1.9.*)

OR

- add any real network layer (svnserve is easy and lightweight choice) for accessing repositories (don't use `file:///` anymore) - in this case old clients can communicate with fresh repositories

OR

- run `svnadmin create` with additional option `--compatible-version` and correct version number as ARG

This is Permissions&Ownership Problem. User, under which Apache is running, **now** can't read filesystem-tree, created by user, used for remote login. Ask local admin "WTF?" and fix errors

- [How to overcome SVN — could not open the requested SVN file system](https://superuser.com/a/449883/99868)
- [SVN Error: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760426/svn-error-could-not-open-the-requested-svn-filesystem)
- [Could not open the requested SVN filesystem on windows7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555804/could-not-open-the-requested-svn-filesystem-on-windows7) (start from answer HERE!!!)

Comment: I do not use file:/// to check in or out files, just added the info about Firefox as perhaps an additional clue. I do not understand what you mean about the clients' hosts since I am using TortoiseSVN 1.9.4 on the clients. BTW the access on the server is through Apache 2.2. Is that a factor?

Comment: @Steve - yes, it **IS MOST IMPORTANT "detail"**, which change ALL!!! You had to write it in question instead of thousands words - because with it my answer become "shot in the air" and wasted time and your question - subject of SuperUser|ServerFault, not SO

Comment: I apologize for the oversight. Unfortunately we are a very small company and I am acting as sysadmin. Admittedly not a very knowledgeable or experienced one. I have downloaded the CollabNet build and set it up. It all now works. Thanks.